# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I use Mac machine to create a virtual environment for Python

```
conda create -n test_python3_9 python=3.9
```

and received these errors:

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: 00:00.022309
CF-RAY: 73e768d0bbde964b-SJC

The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main

As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json` and
associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is
empty. please request that the channel administrator create
`noarch/repodata.json` and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <https://conda.io/docs/config.html>.
```

conda version is conda 4.5.12
and the .condarc file content is:

```
ssl_verify: true
channels:
  - defaults
```

mac version is: Catalina 10.15.7
Do not know how to fix this issue.
Can anyone helps on this?

Thanks,
Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `repodata.json.bz2` was uploaded to the repository `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch` at `2022-08-22 13:19:29 +0000`. For now no need to update anaconda packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with exactly the same problem just few hours ago.

I had tried to change the conda channel(related to the repository) info in the conda configuration file, but it didn't work.

So I Just uninstalled the Anaconda and install the latest version of conda, it works.

If you visit the url 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch' in the errors,
you can see that there is no 'noarch/repodata.json.bz2' file. I think this is the cause of the problem. Old conda version requires that file, but the conda repository does not support it anymore.